# How to replace all non valid characters on utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql

How to replace all non valid characters on utf8_general_ci?

For mysql inserts without problems if user can put emojis or another misc. characters but maintains all compatible characters (a-Z, numbers, characters, quotes, russian text, japan text...)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is way to vague. It's not clear if you want to store high pane Unicode characters (simple: use utf8mb4 instead utf8) or you want to fix a broken app that doesn't use UTF-8 properly (or even fixed invalid data that's already stored). Can you please edit it and provide some details?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the function `utf8_encode()` to make sure only valid caracters are in the provided string.

Note: in MySQL 5.5.3 and up use utf8mb4, rather than utf8, which is the same UTF-8 data format with the same performance but removes a MySQL-specific limitation where only characters up to xFFFD were supported.

If you need some more flexibility or other charsets take a look at `iconv()`. It´s not maintained any more but at least changes in charsets are rare ;-)

Comment: I'm still to see a single day where `utf8_encode()` doesn't show up in a comment or answer as synonym for "fix all encoding issues magically". It's a function that's poorly named but [correctly documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. A more appropriate name for it would be "iso88591_to_utf8". If your text is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function. If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not need this function. In fact, applying this function to text that is not encoded in ISO-8859-1 will most likely simply garble that text.

If you need to convert text from any encoding to any other encoding, look at iconv() instead.